How to inform PhD advisor about your decision to write papers independently?
I'm a physics PhD candidate focusing on quantum information theory. My advisor seems to expect me to be extremely independent. He never suggested what problem to work on, and rarely comments about how to approach the problems I chose to work on. As somebody who likes to solve research problems independently, I began seeing this as a positive trait. Consequently, I independently decided which topics to explore, which methods to use, and eventually decided, what problems to solve for my dissertation. In each stage of this process, my advisor's input was like that of a peer reviewer; He assess my work for their quality, significance and correctness. If something isn't right in my work, he says it isn't right but never suggests nor gives hints about how to fix it.
From what I've heard from other PhD students, PhD advisors work with their student either like a mentor, or like a collaborator. In the former case they tend to help the student think in each step of the research process, and in the latter case they work with the student as equals, solving a common research problem. My advisor doesn't seem to belong to either category. In light of this, I have two concerns/questions:

In the above-described circumstance, is it ethical to write research papers independently, without including my advisor as a co-author? (When I began working with him, he made me sign a student-advisor relationship agreement document, in which the requirement to have him as a co-author in every student publication is a condition. Although I signed the document, I now realize that that condition doesn't make sense at least in my situation).
If so, how do I bring this subject with him without ruining my inter-personal relationship with him?


Are you expecting your advisor to cover page charges?

No. Besides, I'm supported as a TA, as opposed to having a research assistantship.

Are you asking about co-authorship?

(1) acting as a peer reviewer does constitute active involvement (2) have you communicated that you want more/different involvement? When your advisor said something was wrong, did you follow up with further inquiry or go off on your own to change it? (3) have you begun working on a paper together, i.e. an actual product rather than just looking at your results? their input may change and become more significant when there is a tangible product rather than discussions as you work along (4) are you using any resources provided by your advisor?

@R1NaNO, (2) No. I have not communicated about my expectations. In the past, when I followed up my inquiries, I never got any response in that regard, even though he replied to my other emails. So I've learned to become more self reliant. (3) Yes, two papers are under construction. I'm doing all the writing, but I receive feedback from my advisor on pedagogical aspects. (4) I have used some of the papers he asked me to review/ consult.

Is it possible to do this research without his financial support for such things as lab equipment, pay for technical assistants, or other research funding? This is possible in pure math, but not in some lab sciences. Physics can be either. Which is it? That necessity of funding support is the main reason that PIs are usually included in authorship, however the work is done.

@Gliese667  I do not mean has he provided you papers. Has he provided you any resources (computer, software, etc)? Also remember that in the US in most physics departments you don't get a TA for being a freelance student, you get one because you are signed up for research hours under an advisor, and the department is supplementing your salary by having you TA (typically up to a maximum of 20 hours/week). Because you are not paid out of a grant just means you are not beholden to deliverables of a grant, but you are still a group member working under the research enterprise of that advisor.

Btw, having you sign a document obliging you to list them (your advisor) as a co-author on any paper you write is not only bizarre, but surely unethical... hopefully unenforceable. I'd think this is a weird, venal, and untrustworthy person.


How to inform PhD advisor about your decision to write papers independently?

You don't. You discuss the topic with them. Having the attitude of "the decision is made and I'm just informing you" is likely to alienate your advisor, even if they would otherwise agree with your proposal.

He assess my work for their quality, significance and correctness. If something isn't right in my work, he says it isn't right but never suggests nor gives hints about how to fix it

Seems like this could go either way. I understand your point that your advisor is exceptionally hands-off, and they are not paying you, so why do they deserve authorship. But having access to a magic oracle that tells you your work's "quality, significance, and correctness" is an advantage that you should not underestimate. And your advisor may be doing more that is not visible to you.

When I began working with him, he made me sign a student-advisor relationship agreement document, in which the requirement to have him as a co-author in every student publication is a condition. Although I signed the document, I now realize that that condition doesn't make sense

All the more reason to tread lightly here. If single-authored papers are the norm in your field, a reasonable advisor would likely agree to let you publish on your own if you discuss it with them as equals. But if you high-handedly "inform" your advisor that you're backing out of a written agreement and refusing them authorship....well, that could end poorly.

I like this distinction you make between supervisors acting as either a mentor or collaborator. It is much more of a descriptive dichotomy than the "hands on" vs "hands off" characterization.
In terms of writing independently, that is usually fine. If it is your own academic career, then you will be writing a lot independently or with collaborators outside your primarily research lab anyway. However, it depends on the nature of the work and how actively involved a supervisor is. If conceptualization alone can be traced to your supervisor, then that is grounds for discussion. Any work you could imagine they could claim to have some role on, it is worth discussing. However, if you are writing entirely on your own without any guidance from the supervisor, this is pretty reasonable ground to publish or write independently.
Keep in mind it is useful nonetheless to speak with them. They probably will have important input to include that you might not notice and it might enhance the work to get the opinion ot a senior researcher.

This is very field specific, and also very specific to the culture of the department, advisor, research group etc. It sounds like the OP already signed a mentorship agreement to work under that advisor, where what you state is clearly not the modus operandi.

Probably even more supervisory style and lab culture specific. Departments can rarely monitor the output of a single student's research activities. It helps to know if your colleagues in the lab are all asking your supervisor for manuscript preperation, then it is probably not a good idea to be the only one writing independently.

As long as you don't have a PhD degree, you should seek your advisor's approval of your papers before submission, even if you think you can write them independently. If they are well written and the supervisor sees that he/she can improve them only marginally (which is very rarely the case), the supervisor would normally say that he doesn't need to be on the author list, but this decision is not very straightforward and may depend on many other factors. It cannot be just your decision to write papers independently, especially if you rely on the advisor's resources (funding, lab space, established collaborations, samples, etc.). If your supervisor tells you that you should show more independence, it could simply mean that you are not independent enough yet to perform research without being micromanaged all the time.
